# Is "après tout" really equivalent to "after all" in English?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglicismes, lexique

Quelqu’un peut-il me suggérer un connecteur plus approprié que « après tout » dans les phrases :

> « [Après tout], la procédure législative a sa raison d'être ? Si l'autorité absolue tombe dans de mauvaises mains, des dommages terribles peuvent être causés. »

Ma professeure de français n’a pas compris le sens dans ce contexte et j’ai du mal à trouver une alternative. En anglais, j’utiliserais « after all » dans cette phrase.

Comment: Si le point d'interrogation n'est pas une coquille (=typo if you're not familiar with the term) je suggèrerais l'emploi de la forme interrogative.

Answer (score 1):

Oui, grosso modo, après tout !

Ça dépend aussi de la phrase qui précède.  S'il s'agit d'une comparaison, selon le contexte, on peut utiser :

cependant, surtout, en revanche, pourtant, néanmoins, cela dit, en effet, la procédure législative a sa raison d'être.

[Reverso](https://synonyms.reverso.net/synonyme/fr/apr%C3%A8s+tout) donne plusieurs synonymes :

enfin, au fond, en tout cas, ainsi, en effet, de toute manière, quoi qu'il en soit

Answer (score 0):

« Après tout » correspond exactement à « after all » ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apr%C3%A8s_tout)).

Néanmoins, d'autres expressions pourraient être utilisées.

- Quoi qu'on en pense/Quoi qu'il en soit/Quoi qu'on en dise, la procédure législative a sa raison d'être;